# do plain texts in html have kinda its own top margin, glued to it?

Tags: html, css

i created div, set its paddings to 0 and added some text inside of it. i noticed that  there was almost no space between left border of div and text, while there was  2-3 pixel space(increases together with font size)  between  top border and text. so when you type a text it defaultly gets some space on top of it, which acts like a margin. am i wright?   here is the code

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 0;
    border: black 1px solid;
    }
</style>
<div> This is some random text. jjj </div>
```

Comment: am not sure what you really mean but i am assuming you know that the body has its default margin of 8px. But since you saying it only appears on the top...did u put `margin: 0` for body ?

Comment: Nope, rather, they mean that within the `border` they created in the `div`, there is a space between the top border and the text within the `div`.

Comment: Ohhh... !! right ! :P :) @EyasSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, plain text has no default margin. Besides, if there were a margin, it would appear outside the border; the spacing between content and border is *padding*. But there is no default padding either. (Some HTML elements like `td` have default padding, but most don’t, and the padding is a property of the element, not of text content.)

The empty space that you may see above and below a text character, between it and the element border if a border is drawn, is caused by two factors (in addition to padding, if a padding is set).

First, it’s part of the design of the glyph, i.e. the visual rendering of a character. Glyphs are designed using a conceptual framework, with the *height of a font* as one part. The height of a glyph is generally much smaller than that height; usually there is space even above uppercase letters. Most glyphs—with the exception of letters like j and g—don’t extend below the *baseline* of text. All of this depends on the font. It cannot be affected except by the choice of a font.

Second, the *line height*, i.e. the distance between baselines of texts, is usually somewhat larger than the font height. This causes spacing below and above a line. This spacing can be removed, by setting `line-height` to 1 (called “setting solid” in traditional typography), or even turned to negative, within some limits, by setting `line-height` to a value smaller than 1. Usually this is not a good idea except for isolated one-liners.

The following illustrates how choice of a font and `line-height` affect the spacing.

```html
<style type="text/css">
div {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 0;
    border: black 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* to keep the divs separated */
    }
</style>
<div style="font-family: Times New Roman"> This is some random text. jjj </div>
<div style="font-family: Arial"> This is some random text. jjj </div>
<div style="font-family: Arial; line-height: 1"> This is some random text. jjj </div>
<div style="font-family: Arial; line-height: 0.8"> This is some random text. jjj </div>
<div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial; line-height: 1">Glyphs like Å and Ê may extend
beyond the top or bottom of the font. So may glyphs like þ and ẹ.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than HTML text having its own "margin", it is that elements have a default `line-height` property that is larger than the amount taken by the font.

[The MDN article on `line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) explains that the default value of line-height is `normal`, which evaluates to something that is dependent on the user agent (the browser). On most browsers, they say, the line height is something like 1.2 times the font weight (i.e. ~`1.2em`).

The recommended way to set `line-height` is to just use the `<number>` format, according to MDN, which uses a unit-less number as a multiplier to the current font-size. For instance: Attempting to add to your `div` CSS rule:

```
line-height: 1; /* set line-height to be 1.0 * your font size */
```

You can alternatively set `line-height` to be a specific pixel length, of course.

Comment: well,  setting line height to 100% does not change a thing, but setting it 35 pixels, makes  top-border set just above the text with no spaces left between them, while lower part of text gets outside of bottom-border .

Comment: My impression is that the default `line-height: normal;` is eqivalent to `line-height: 1.2;`. Compare on your own browser `line-height: 1.2;` and `line-height 1;`. You could, of course, also use smaller multipliers.

Comment: Length and percentage property types (`em` and `%`) seem to have poor inheritance behavior. The MDN article recommends unitless properties, which is what I have updated my post to indicate.